# how do i make my program execute the if conditon in javascript because it directly goes to else condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

the program asks the user to choose between clicking ok to continue in the alert or
cancel to quit, the problem is that it just directly executes the else condition and skips the if condition and here is the code

```
var y;
y = prompt("what is your name ?","someone")

if (y == true) {
    var x = ("hello "+y);
    alert(x);
    var a = ("thanks for your visit");
    alert(a);
}
else {
    alert("error");
}
```

Comment: If you print the value of `y` after prompting the user, what gets printed?

Comment: if the user writes for example "Jimmy" ,it prompts "Jimmy" , in this case is it "someone" by default

Comment: `y == true` will never be `true`. You're comparing a string to a boolean. I think what you're meaning to do is `if(y)`. The variable `y` will never be `true`, but non-empty strings in JavaScript are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). While `"asd" == true` would return `false`, `if("asd")` would execute the `if` statement because a non-empty string is truthy and the `if` statement treats it *as if* it's `true`.

Comment: i was told that in the alert, "ok" means true and "cancel" means false, what i mean is that i want the program to execute the if conditon after clicking "ok" in the alert.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of a `confirm` popup instead of `prompt` popup - `confirm` will return true/false.

Comment: i actually changed the condition from if (y==true) to if (y) and it works correctly now, thanks for both of you

Answer (score 4):

Since the cancel button returns `null` You should change the if statement to `y != null`.